# importlib.reload donot work after change lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, reload

I write func.py:

```
def test_reload():
    print("123")
```

Package it and install it in python3.9.
Run it python3.9:

```
>from pgk.func import test_reload
>test_reload()
123
```

it print "123",now change func.py：

```
def test_reload():
    print("abc")
```

then package and install again.
continue to python3.9,try to reload:

```
>import pgk
>import importlib
>importlib.reload(pgk)
>test_reload()
123
>from pgk.func import test_reload
>test_reload()
123
```

It still shows "123" not "abc".

please help to fix, how reload correct?

Comment: You never imported `pgk` before you loaded `test_reload`, so reloading it isn't going to change anything.  Not sure how to reload a single function rather than a whole module.

Comment: you mean import pkg before change code?